# Cannot forward after response has been committed in Servlet with try-catch resource

Tags: java, servlets

The below method throw: Servlet.service() for servlet DetailCakeServlet threw exception
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed.`

**Code**

```
 try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        CakeDAO dao = new CakeDAO();
        String strID = request.getParameter("id");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(strID);
        request.setAttribute("cake", dao.getCakeById(id));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/detail.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

But when I remove the resource out object, it works. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Need to learn how to ask a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Please edit your question with these : #1. Give more details on the error (you can paste the error stack at least 10-15 lines which gives more view on the problem you face. #2. "When I remove the resource out object" - which is that object (specify line number or give more details). People won't try to answer a question if they do not understand it by reading. The more details you provide, the more chance to get it answered !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do a forwarding without output:

```
try {
    CakeDAO dao = new CakeDAO();
    String strID = request.getParameter("id");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(strID);
    request.setAttribute("cake", dao.getCakeById(id));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/detail.jsp").forward(request, response);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

or do:

```
try {
    CakeDAO dao = new CakeDAO();
    String strID = request.getParameter("id");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(strID);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Cake: " + dao.getCakeById(id)); // Hereafter an exception would err.
    // NEVER forward: ... .forward(request, response);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Try-with-resources automatically closes, and is not needed. On forwarding even an error is raised.

More importantly, *without* getting the writer, you are better of. After output is actually written (buffered I/O!), a forwarding is erroneous, so the forwarding in catch is dirty.

Comment: I have tried case 2 with a forwarding after in try block, it still work?

Comment: getWriter ordinarily will return a BufferedWriter. As long as the first buffer is not actually written (flushed), one may still forward. Better is to return an **error code** like 500, `HttpServletResponse.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`. Then the app maps to a configurable error page.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html#catch-block) (haven't found it quickly in the specification), *before the catch block is entered, the try-with-resources construct will attempt to close the resources opened inside the try block* - i.e. your `out`, and thus the `response`, is already closed when you try to redirect in the `catch` block. I would suggest to handle possible exceptions the following way:

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
  try {
    CakeDAO dao = new CakeDAO();
    String strID = request.getParameter("id");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(strID);
    request.setAttribute("cake", dao.getCakeById(id));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/detail.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }catch (Exception ex) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

Actually, I don't see any use of `out` in your code, so the whole try-with-resources block is just superfluous.